# Low quality legends produced by Latex interpreter in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, interpreter

I have used latex interpreter in the plot command in MATLAB (R2014b) to produce especial characters and hat in the figure legends.
The quality of the texts in the legend became rather bad and when I copy the figure to use it in my word document; it is hard to identify the subscript of the variables so it is not suitable to be used in the article.
The command that I have used is this:
legend({'${\rho}_1(\hat{\theta})$','$\rho_1(\theta)$',},1,'Interpreter','latex');

I appreciate any help on this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: what code do you use to copy/export the figure?

Comment: I use "copy figure" from the "Edit" menu in the figure window.

Comment: I use "copy figure" from the "Edit" menu in the figure window in MATLAB. The problem is that the original figure in MATLAB has legend texts with low quality resolution so I think the problem is not happening because of export/copy procedure.